# Ellipsis problem - Orbit of a planet around a star

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I am given the following problem:

> Suppose that P is a planet that describes an elliptical orbit around the star O located at ( 0,0 ). Based on the image below, find the distance from P to O.

[image]

What I have so far is the distance between the focus points and O:

\begin{align*}
a &= 10\\
b &= 5\\
100 &= 25+c^2 \therefore c = \sqrt{75}
\end{align*}

I am not sure how to proceed now. I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Obviously this problem was not written by a physicist. :-/

Comment: @BrianTung, I was about to make the same comment! The planet should be at one of the foci!! Note that "the distance between the focus points and O" is an incorrect use of focus point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by forming a right triangle as shown.

$\hskip{.75in}$[image: ellipse]

From here, remember that

$$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{x}{y}.$$

Since $\alpha = 45^\circ$, and $\tan(45^\circ) = 1$, this leads us to:

$$ 1 = \frac{x}{y} \quad \Rightarrow \quad y=x.$$

Since you found $a = 10$, $b=5$ and we are given the center is $(0,0)$, we then know this ellipse has the standard form

$$ \frac{x^2}{100} + \frac{y^2}{25} = 1.$$

Since $y=x$, this turns into:
$$ \frac{x^2}{100} + \frac{x^2}{25} = 1.$$

Solving for $x$ in this equation will give you $P$. Then use the distance formula to find what the question is asking.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you, yes I can! Thanks!

Comment: @bru1987 Awesome! You are welcome!